# Simple Enrutador con PHP pero con parametros POST o GET

Tags: php, router

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en PHP y necesito definir un enrutador, simple y limpio.
Escribi algo como lo siguiente, y hace su trabajo pero al momento de enviar parametros GET o POST, no recibo nada en el fichero PHP del "Require"...

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($request) {
  case '/' :
      require __DIR__ . '/sp_index.php';
      break;

  case '' :
      require __DIR__ . '/sp_index.php';
      break;

  case '/mantenimiento' :
      require __DIR__ . '/sp_mantenimiento.php';
      break;

  case '/planes' :
      require __DIR__ . '/sp_planes.php';
      break;

  case '/contacta' :
      require __DIR__ . '/sp_contacta.php';
      break;

  case '/nosotros' :
      require __DIR__ . '/sp_nosotros.php';
      break;

  case '/soporte' :
      require __DIR__ . '/sp_support.php';
      break;

  case '/privacidad' :
      require __DIR__ . '/sp_privacy.php';
      break;

  default:
      http_response_code(404);
      require __DIR__ . '/sp_error_404.php';
      break;
}
```

Pero cuando envío parámetros get o post a la ruta no recibo nada.

Alguna idea?

Estaba pensando algo como enviar $_REQUEST a través de una variable global pero no se si implica temas de seguridad.

La aplicación la estoy realizado completamente en PHP a medida tal vez me podrian recomendar alguna clase, idea o algun snippet para esto?

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es probable que `$request` no tenga una diagonal al principio, de ser el caso, agrégala:

```
if($request[0] != '/') {
    $request = '/' . $request;
}
```

Con POST no deberías tener problema, porque no agrega información en url, caso contrario de GET, pero puedes solucionarlo eliminando ? y todo lo que venga después:

```
// Esto devuelve un array con 1 elemento si no encuentra ?
// o dos elementos si es que lo encuentra
$partes = explode('?', $request);
// Usa solo el primer elemento, porque lo demás son parámetros GET
$request = $partes[0];
```

Por otra parte, sería más fácil crear un array para facilitar el manejo de tus rutas, por que también puedes incluir otra información útil para crear menús, por ejemplo:

```
$rutas = [
    '/' => ['Página principal', 'sp_index.php'],
    '/mantenimiento' => ['Mantenimiento', 'sp_mantenimiento.php'],
    '/privacidad' => ['Privacidad', 'sp_privacidad.php'],
];

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($request[0] != '/') {
    $request = '/' . $request;
}
$partes = explode('?', $request);
$request = $partes[0];

// Verificar si hay página o no
if(isset($rutas[$request])) {
    // Incluir el PHP adecuado
    include __DIR__ . '/' . $rutas[$request][1];
} else {
    // La página no existe
    http_response_code(404);
    include __DIR__ . '/sp_error_404.php';
}
```

También se puede usar `$rutas` para crear menús:

```
// Definir URL base del proyecto
$url = 'http://localhost/proyecto';
foreach($rutas as $param => $valores) {
    echo "<a href="$url$param">{$valores[0]}</a>";
}
```

En cuanto a recibir información en los archivos incluidos solo necesitas usar $_GET o $_POST, según el caso y no es necesario aplicar `global`, porque estas variables son `super globales` y siempre están disponibles.

Si aún tienes problemas para acceder a los parámetros GET, entonces hay que revisar tu .htaccess, que probablemente los está eliminando. Pero debería ser más o menos así:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

En Las condiciones:
`!-f` Aplica si el archivo solicitado no existe
`!-d` Aplica si la carpeta solicitada no existe

En la redirección:
`L` Si se cumplieron las condiciones, aplica la regla y finaliza
`QSA` Envía a PHP los parámetros que puedan existir ?par1=val1&par2=val2...etc